# addSiteAccount Returns siteAccountId even if credentials are incorrect

Tags: yodlee

I would like to differentiate between two scenarios: `addSiteAccount` API with incorrect credentials and `addSiteAccount` API with right set of credentials. What I am noticing is that both cases return a siteAccountId with RefreshStatus=Triggered. But when I invoke the same API again or any other API then I get a Login error message.

How can I distinguish between the two cases in a single execution of `addSiteAccount` ?

So that I could pass the error to end users about incorrect credentials. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`addSiteAccount1` is the API which will create a `siteaccountID` i.e. an identifier for that particular account linked.
It will not return any error until you are trying to add same credentials i.e. in that case it will check if you already have added those credentials and will return the response for those credentials.

**For understanding how it works:**

After calling addSiteAccount1 a siteAccountId willbe created and a refresh would be initiated for that. This will go ahead and validate the credentials passed with the Bank web site and will return the response(success or failure depending upon the credentials passed).

For checking status you need to call `getSiteRefreshInfo` in loop, I am mentioning the flow for your reference.

**(Applicable only for NON- MFA sites)**

1. CobLogin
2. Register3
3. Login
4. AddSiteAccount1 – (this will trigger a refresh request,no need to call startSiteRefresh)
5. Check for siteRefreshStatus field’s value returned from #4 and if it says “REFRESH_TRIGGERED” , then you can go to #6
6. Call getSiteRefreshInfo in loop till you get SiteRefreshStatus as either of the following status is received

**PARTIAL_COMPLETE–** This means that the account level data has been aggregated
**REFRESH_COMPLETED–** The refresh has been completed.

**LOGIN_FAILURE–** Login credentials provided was wrong.

**REFRESH_CANCELLED–** Refresh cancelled by User.

**REFRESH_TIMED_OUT–** Refresh is taking more time.

7   From #6 you also get a “code” and if the code is **402** then that means credentials were wrong and if it's 0(zero) that means the credentials were correct and the gathering of data was successful. Then you can go to #8 and grab transactions.
Also to know more about error_code see [ErrorCode](https://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes) document.

8   ExecuteUserSearchRequest or call any other API depending upon your implementation.